# If stop iss default website still get response in SignalR client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, signalr

We are using Windows server 2016. We have client/web application to check server is running(not stopped) and accordingly displaying button as connected on the web/client application page.

Our signalR API hosted as default website on iis server if we stop it then still get a response from signalR API server.

Note : its only work when we stop the whole iss server or created separate web application rather than default website.

```
<input type="text" id="msg" value=" " />
    <input type="button" id="send" value="send" />
    <div id="message">
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js"></script>    
    <script>

        var connection = $.hubConnection('http://websitename/WebApi/signalr');
        //connection.logging = true;

        var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('SignalRHub');
        console.log(connection);
        console.log(proxy);

        connection.stateChanged(function (change) {
            console.log(change);
            console.log($.signalR.connectionState);
            if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.reconnecting) {
                console.log("liveFeed is reconnecting!");
            }
            else if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {
                console.log("liveFeed is connected!");
                connection.start().done(function (data) {
                    console.log('Now connected ', data);
                    proxy.invoke('GetRealTime');
                }).fail(function (er) {
                    console.log(er);
                });
            }
            while (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected) {
                console.log("in while loop")
                connection.start().done(function (data) {
                    console.log('Now connected ', data);
                    proxy.invoke('GetRealTime');
                }).fail(function (er) {
                    console.log(er);
                });
            }
        });

        proxy.on('setRealTime', function (obj) {
            var text = $('#message').html();
            $('#message').html(JSON.stringify(obj));
        });

        connection.disconnected(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert('Server has disconnected');
        });

        connection.start().done(function (data) {
            console.log('Now connected ', data);
            proxy.invoke('GetRealTime');
        }).fail(function (er) {
            console.log(er);
        });


    </script>
```

Comment: Could you please post more details information about how you host your signalR application in the IIS? Does the signalR application hosted on the default web sie in IIS and you stop the default web site?

Answer (score 0):

Are you stopping your application pool when you stop the website? Stopping your application pool (not all of IIS, meaning W3SVC service is still running, other sites can run, etc...) would shut down all of your server side code (SignalR, etc...). Only stopping your site would still leave SignalR running in the application pool.

If you are using default application pool for all your sites, separate those. Stop just your SignalR website and application pool. You should see a difference when your client detects a state change in connection.